# Android Relative Layout issues with positioning Button

Tags: android

I am having Android Relative Layout design view in my Android Studio project. I have two buttons horizontally in this view. I am facing 2 issues.

1. I am unable to properly move button separately. If i move button 1, button 2 is also moving along. How can we able to move button separately?
2. My app is supported for Phone and Tab. But, If i move the buttons in some position for tab, it does't display properly when i install the app on phone. Background images and all are working fine on both screens.
   How to set native button positions to work with both tab screen and phone screen as well?

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MyActivity"
   android:background="@drawable/bg">

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/PlayPauseButton"
       android:layout_marginBottom="103dp"
       android:onClick="doClick"
       android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="82dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/StopButton"
       android:onClick="stopAudio"
       android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/PlayPauseButton"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/PlayPauseButton"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/PlayPauseButton" />
   ```

Comment: So, where is your code? BTW You need to create a separate layout for different screen size.

Comment: Show your xml file. You can achieve it by making different layout folder for tablets or you can use by `dimens.xml` file in different `values` folder.

Comment: You should also upload your XML so it will easier to get answer for your problem ..

Comment: There is no issues with view. It is showing properly with background image set in both Phone and Tab. I am seeing problem only with Button positioning.

Answer (score 0):

you should have to use LinearLayout and set the weightsum
so it will be always seperate either in phone or tablet. see example of code:-

```
  <LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                      
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"             
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"       
   tools:context=".MyActivity"
   android:background="@drawable/bg"
   android:weightSum="1">

  <Button
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/PlayPauseButton"
     android:layout_marginBottom="103dp"
     android:onClick="doClick"
     android:layout_weight="0.50"
   />

   <Button
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/StopButton"
      android:onClick="stopAudio"
      android:layout_weight="0.50"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think, This is good. Can I have both of the buttons moved to bottom and place it center horizontally?

Comment: yes you can moved the buttons wherever u want and place it any places

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to move smoothly the buttons in design view. This was the problem when I had relative layout design also. If I move left side button to right, right side button automatically moves right as well, and vice versa. Moving to bottom I need to set layout:gravity=bottom, otherwise i can't move it down.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 : Second button moves relative to first button because it is aligned to that button via

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/PlayPauseButton"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/PlayPauseButton"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/PlayPauseButton"
```